# In Matlab how do I change the arrow head style in quiver plot?

Tags: matlab, vector, plot

I would like to change the default arrow head style in quiver plot. How can I change it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**For Matlab Version > R2014b**

Since R2014b version, Matlab has modified the structure of its graphical components. Here is the up-to-date code that uses Matlab's *annotations*.

[image]

is produced by

```
headWidth = 8;
headLength = 8;
LineLength = 0.08;

%some data
[x,y] = meshgrid(0:0.2:2,0:0.2:2);
u = cos(x).*y;
v = sin(x).*y;

%quiver plots
figure('Position',[10 10 1000 600],'Color','w');
hax_1 = subplot(1,2,1);
hq = quiver(x,y,u,v);           %get the handle of quiver
title('Regular Quiver plot','FontSize',16);

%get the data from regular quiver
U = hq.UData;
V = hq.VData;
X = hq.XData;
Y = hq.YData;

%right version (with annotation)
hax_2 = subplot(1,2,2);
%hold on;
for ii = 1:length(X)
    for ij = 1:length(X)

        headWidth = 5;
        ah = annotation('arrow',...
            'headStyle','cback1','HeadLength',headLength,'HeadWidth',headWidth);
        set(ah,'parent',gca);
        set(ah,'position',[X(ii,ij) Y(ii,ij) LineLength*U(ii,ij) LineLength*V(ii,ij)]);

    end
end
%axis off;
title('Quiver - annotations ','FontSize',16);

linkaxes([hax_1 hax_2],'xy');
```

Please note that this piece of code changes the head style and controls for the length of the line (in the left panel, you can see that arrows overlap on the upper-left part of the left subplot, while it does not on the right subplot). The length and width of the arrow heads are not modified.

For this edit, I didn't keep the colors scheme that coded for the angle, and discarded the dynamic head size. It makes things clearer.

---

**For Matlab Version < R2014b**

Quiver plots are hard to modify. As @Luis Mendo said, you can modify the quiver function within the matlab install. However, you will still be limited by the complexity of programmatically drawing arrows with nice patches/lines. There might be an easier route using `annotation` - see the "Quiver - annotation" subplot that sets the `headStyle` property to `cback1`.

[Annotations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) are graphical objects (lines, textboxes, arrows, ...) that you can be easily inserted by hand once a plot is done. They display additional text or point to a particular area for example. You can also insert them programmatically by defining their positions - and that's the option we will take. We first draw a regular `quiver` plot (left panel), get the blue lines' `X` and `Y` data, and use these coordinates to insert annotation arrows, each of them being displayed at the exact same location (same position, same angle, same size; right panel).

Annotation arrows have some nice properties you can easily modify, such as `Color`, `HeadWidth`, `HeadLength`, and `HeadStyle`. In the following plot, I modified each arrow's color depending on its angle against the x-axis, and `headWidth` that depends length.

The following picture

[image]

is produced by

```
%some data
[x,y] = meshgrid(0:0.2:2,0:0.2:2);
u = cos(x).*y;
v = sin(x).*y;

%quiver plots
figure('Position',[10 10 1000 600],'Color','w');
hax_1 = subplot(1,2,1);

%left version (regular)
hq1 = quiver(x,y,u,v);

%get the line position (first handle)
hkid = get(hq1,'children');
X = get(hkid(1),'XData');
Y = get(hkid(1),'YData');
axis off;
title('Quiver - regular ','FontSize',16);

%right version (with annotation)
hax_2 = subplot(1,2,2);
cmap = jet(116); %colormap, 116 because angles goes up to 115 degrees

for ii = 1:3:length(X)-1

    headWidth = 200 * sqrt((X(ii+1)-X(ii)).^2 + (Y(ii+1)-Y(ii)).^2); % set the headWidth, function of length of arrow
    angled = floor(atan2(Y(ii+1)-Y(ii),X(ii+1)-X(ii))*180/pi) + 1; %get the angle
    ah = annotation('arrow',...
        'Color', cmap(angled,:),...
        'headStyle','cback1','HeadLength',50,'HeadWidth',headWidth);
    set(ah,'parent',gca);
    set(ah,'position',[X(ii) Y(ii) X(ii+1)-X(ii) Y(ii+1)-Y(ii)]);
end
axis off;
title('Quiver - annotations ','FontSize',16);

linkaxes([hax_1 hax_2],'xy');
```

Answer (score 7):

The file `refresh.m` located in folder `...\MATLAB\...\toolbox\matlab\specgraph\@specgraph\@quivergroup\@quivergroup` contains the following lines:

```
%// Arrow head parameters
alpha = .33;  %// Size of arrow head relative to the length of the vector
beta = .25;  %// Width of the base of the arrow head relative to the length
```

Changing the values of `alpha` and `beta` achieves the desired effect.

However, this entails modifying Matlab's files, and thus it's not recommended. If you do it, keep a copy of the original `refresh.m` file.

---

Results using the example code that appears in `quiver`'s help:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-2:.2:2,-1:.15:1);
z = x .* exp(-x.^2 - y.^2); [px,py] = gradient(z,.2,.15);
quiver(x,y,px,py), hold off, axis image
```

- With original parameters (`alpha = .33;` `beta = .25;`):

  [image]
- With `alpha = .5;` `beta = .5;`:

  [image]

Comment: How exactly do you use these parameters?

Comment: I used the which command to find out the m file for quiver, and changed those parameters, but this takes no effect whatsoever. I am using r2012b.

Comment: @qed You're right, they make no effect. It appears that the actual used `alpha` and `beta` are in `...\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\specgraph\@specgraph\@quivergroup\@specgraph\@quivergroup\refresh.m`

Answer (score 3):

You can start here:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html

and then you can look for the available properties of quiver here:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quivergroupproperties.html

For example, the property MaxHeadSize allows to change the size of the arrow-heads.

**EDIT:** More information in this link: [Arrow properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/adding-arrows-and-lines-to-graphs.html#f0-37405)

Read at bottom, where says

> You can select an annotation and then choose Show M-code to obtain a
>   code snippet that you can insert in a function or script to reproduce
>   the annotation.

Comment: I found that, but what I need is the head style, not size. I could not find any properties for HeadStyle.

Comment: Take a look on this link: [Arrow properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/adding-arrows-and-lines-to-graphs.html#f0-37405).
Read at bottom, where says `You can select an annotation and then choose Show M-code to obtain a code snippet that you can insert in a function or script to reproduce the annotation.`

Answer (score 2):

This answer of [pablo1977](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18776328/1714410) was the most instructive for me. I managed to get bigger arrow heads by adjusting the quiver group properties, namely by these 2 lines of code:

```
h = quiver(...);
set(h,'MaxHeadSize',1e2,'AutoScaleFactor',1);
```

Comment: @Rufflewind I disagree with you. This answer, albeit short, is not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Check out arrow3() from the MATLAB file-exchange

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14056-arrow3

In addition to these examples.

https://kr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/14056/versions/16/previews/arrow3_examples.html

It is faster than the annotation command, and produces similar results.
Using the above examples

```
headWidth =0.8;  % 1/10 of annotation
headLength=0.8;  % 1/10 of annotation
LineLength = 0.08; % same as annotation


[x,y] = meshgrid(0:0.2:2,0:0.2:2);
u = cos(x).*y;
v = sin(x).*y;

figure();
%hq = quiver(x,y,u,v);
p1 = [x(:) y(:)]; % data start point
u = u(:); v=v(:);
arrow3(p1,p1+LineLength*[u,v],'k',headWidth,headLength);
```

Sorry I can't post a picture of this plotted, since I need to earn more reputation points. The arrowheads are closed and all similar size, like the annotation command would give.