# Matlab how to fill quiver arrow heads

Tags: matlab, plot

I am making a [quiver plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html) :

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(0:0.2:2,0:0.2:2);
u = cos(x).*y;
v = sin(x).*y;
figure
quiver(x,y,u,v)
```

I want the arrow heads to be filled (i.e [image] and not [image])

From the documentation, it should be pretty straightforward by using

```
quiver(...,LineSpec,'filled')
```

However, I still couldn't figure out the right syntax - these do not work :

```
quiver(x,y,u,v,'LineWidth','filled');
quiver(x,y,u,v,'LineWidth',1,'filled');
```

Thanks for your help!

---

edit : Using line specifiers does the following:

```
quiver(x,y,u,v) %Original
```

[image]

```
quiver(x,y,u,v,'-sk','filled') %With line specifiers
```

[image]

Comment: the [LineSpec](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html) is generally a string such as `'-k'` for a black line, and `'filled'` refers to the point markers which can be specified. For example `'-sk'` which gives squares however these will replace the arrows heads from quiver.   To modify the quivers I suggest you take a look at [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776172/in-matlab-how-do-i-change-the-arrow-head-style-in-quiver-plot).

Comment: @RTL : Thanks for the reference for the other question it is indeed helpful, but I figure (as suggested by the docs) there should be a simpler way to do this. Regarding LineSpec, it is a good direction but the specifiers do not to include all the regular specs in general and specifically : "quiver(x,y,u,v,'Linestyle','-sk')" seem not to be a valid syntax.

Comment: try `quiver(x,y,u,v,'-sk')` the 'linestyle' is not needed.  I'm afraid I don't know of a simpler way... (its worth comparing with `quiver(x,y,u,v,'-sk','filled')` to see the effect of filled)

Comment: What you're asking is not easy to achieve as Matlab constructs every arrow in the quiver plot from to line objects: one for the tail and one for the head. Thus, the style of the arrow head cannot be changed like for `annotation('arrow',...)`. A possible approach would be to replace every arrow head line object with a polygon using `fill(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a MATLAB professional, so please excuse if my answer is clunky. I am sure there are more elegant ways to solve this - the following is the one I found.

I decided to solve this retrieving the positions of the arrow tips, deleting them and repaint them with `fill` (like Deve suggested). I noticed that I can tell `fill` that one polygon ends and the next begins through inserting `NaN` values (thats also the way the original arrow tips are drawn, as you can see inspecting the original `XData`). Doing so I lost the possibility to influence the color of the objects and they didn´t get filled. As a work-around I painted the new arrow-tips in a loop - I know there might be a better way to do it, so I am happy about any addition.

I used the example you gave, only replacing the last line by
`HANDLE = quiver(x,y,u,v);` to get the handle to the plot. From there on:

```
children=get(handle,'children'); % retrieve the plot-children - 
                                 % second element are the arrow tips

XData=get(children(2),'XData'); % retrieve the coordinates of the tips
YData=get(children(2),'YData');

hold on
delete(children(2))  % delete old arrow tips

for l=1:4:length(XData)-3   % paint new arrow tips, skipping the NaN-values
    ArrowTips((l-1)/4+1)=fill(XData(l:l+2),YData(l:l+2),'r');
end
```

You can then find the handles to the arrow-tips in the ArrowTips-variable. Feel free to specify the Edge- and Facecolor in the call to `fill`, here being black and red respectively.

Comment: Sorry, messed up different approaches. I updated the code, now it should work. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

This code in an answer to a similar question works quite well, actually. It uses annotations.

[In Matlab how do I change the arrow head style in quiver plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776172/in-matlab-how-do-i-change-the-arrow-head-style-in-quiver-plot)

Comment: Please give a brief description of what that question page's content is and how does it solve this question.