# How to draw an arrow in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm trying to draw an arrow in matlab graph, without any success.

Code example:

```
function [ output_args ] = example( input_args )

figure ('Name', 'example');
x = [10 30]
y = [10 30]
xlim([1, 100])
ylim([1, 100])
arrow (x, y) ???
end
```

Is there any function in matlab that can draw arrow ?
Thanks

Comment: when using "annotation('arrow',x,y)" Im getting error... ?

Comment: how are you using it? what do you enter? anyway there are 2 answers below already...

Comment: In the case of publication quality graphics, my solution is sadly to give up fighting with Matlab, export to EPS, and use Adobe Illustrator when I need things like arrows and precise text. It sucks, but I'm a lot happier, and the resulting figures look much better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the (well-documented) [DaVinci Draw toolbox](http://davinci-draw.com) (full disclosure: I wrote/sell the toolbox, though arrows are free).  Example syntax and example output are below.

```
davinci( 'arrow', 'X', [0 10], 'Y', [0 2], <plus-lots-of-options> )
```

[image]

Answer (score 65):

You could abuse [**`quiver`**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html), this way you don't have to deal with unhandy normalized figure units by use of `annotation`

```
drawArrow = @(x,y) quiver( x(1),y(1),x(2)-x(1),y(2)-y(1),0 )    

x1 = [10 30];
y1 = [10 30];

drawArrow(x1,y1); hold on

x2 = [25 15];
y2 = [15 25];

drawArrow(x2,y2)
```

[image]

Important is the **5th** argument of `quiver`: **0** which disables an otherwise default scaling, as this function is actually used to plot vector fields. (or use the poperty value pair `'AutoScale','off'`)

You can also add additional features:

```
drawArrow = @(x,y,varargin) quiver( x(1),y(1),x(2)-x(1),y(2)-y(1),0, varargin{:} )       
drawArrow(x1,y1); hold on
drawArrow(x2,y2,'linewidth',3,'color','r')
```

[image]

If you don't like the arrowheads, you need to go back to annotations and this answer is may helpful:

[**How do I change the arrow head style in quiver plot?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776172/in-matlab-how-do-i-change-the-arrow-head-style-in-quiver-plot)

---

Some remarks regarding the comments:

The arrow head size can be adjust with the `'MaxHeadSize'` property, it's not consistent unfortunately. The axes limits need to be set **afterwards**

```
x1 = [10 30];
y1 = [10 30];
drawArrow(x1,y1,{'MaxHeadSize',0.8,'Color','b','LineWidth',3}); hold on

x2 = [25 15];
y2 = [15 25];
drawArrow(x2,y2,{'MaxHeadSize',10,'Color','r','LineWidth',3}); hold on

xlim([1, 100])
ylim([1, 100])
```

[image]

---

[The solution by sed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25732096/2605073) seems to be the best, because it offers adjustable arrow heads.

I'd just would wrap it into a function:

```
function [ h ] = drawArrow( x,y,xlimits,ylimits,props )

xlim(xlimits)
ylim(ylimits)

h = annotation('arrow');
set(h,'parent', gca, ...
    'position', [x(1),y(1),x(2)-x(1),y(2)-y(1)], ...
    'HeadLength', 10, 'HeadWidth', 10, 'HeadStyle', 'cback1', ...
    props{:} );

end
```

which you can call from your script as follows:

```
drawArrow(x1,y1,[1, 100],[1, 100],{'Color','b','LineWidth',3}); hold on
drawArrow(x2,y2,[1, 100],[1, 100],{'Color','r','LineWidth',3}); hold on
```

giving you quite similar results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, But if i want to see the graphs limit (1..100) is it possible ?

Comment: add `xlim([1, 100]); ylim([1, 100])` just as always

Comment: it will work if you write the `xlim`,`ylim` after the `drawarrow`. The only issue is that the arrow head wont look big enough in my view...

Comment: @natan you can adjust that by `'MaxHeadSize'`, see edit.

Comment: yes, but the point is that you'll need to play with the proper size for each selection of coordinates and axis limits. In case you'll have limits of [1 10] and arrows from [3 8] you'll get huge arrow heads... So this works great, but you need also to add automatic some arrow head estimator to the solution... something like `arrowsize=0.15*abs(diff(xlim).^2+dif(Ylim).^2)`

Comment: @natan yes I agree, it's just not the best solution ;)

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`arrow` from the file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/278-arrow-m). `arrow(Start,Stop)` draws a line with an arrow from Start to Stop (points should be vectors of length 2 or 3, or matrices with 2 or 3 columns), and returns the graphics handle of the arrow(s).

**Edit:** @Lama is also right, you can use [`annotation`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) but you need to take into account the plot limits.

```
annotation('arrow',x,y)
```

creates an arrow annotation object that extends from the point defined by x(1),y(1) to the point defined by x(2),y(2), specified in **normalized figure units**. You can use the 
[Data space to figure units conversion](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10656-data-space-to-figure-units-conversion) function (ds2nfu.m) from the file exchange to make your life easier.

```
[xf yf]=ds2nfu(x,y);
annotation(gcf,'arrow', xf,yf)
```

[image]

Note that there are some undocumented features that allow pinning annotations to graphs if that is needed, read more about it [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/pinning-annotations-to-graphs)...

Answer (score 7):

Amongst other solutions, here is one using `annotation` where you can set the arrow properties including `(x,y,width,height)` **within the current axes**, the head and line properties.

```
h=annotation('arrow');
set(h,'parent', gca, ...
    'position', [50 5 20 2], ...
    'HeadLength', 1000, 'HeadWidth', 100, 'HeadStyle', 'hypocycloid', ...
    'Color', [0.4 0.1 0.8], 'LineWidth', 3);
```

gives

[image]

Comment: +1 in my eyes best non-File-Exchange solution. I pimped your idea a little to make it more versatile.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use for example

```
text(x,y,'\leftarrow t_1','FontSize',12,'FontWeight','bold')
```

[See illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx4LH.png)