# How to create the curved arrow in Matlab

Tags: matlab

[image]

While plotting straight lines may be a straightforward task, the process becomes more intricate when dealing with curved arrows in Matlab. Specialized arrow tools, as found in software like SmartDraw, can be advantageous, allowing one to create various arrow types, including curved arrows, with minimal effort. But in the case of Matlab, I have no idea to plot such curved arrows. Please suggest.

Comment: You might like the `circular_arrow` function on [File Exchange](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/59917-circular_arrow)

Comment: Related (partial duplicate but extends to 3D): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895072/curved-arrows-in-matlab