# How to create diagonal arrow in a figure using 'latex arrow symbol'?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want to show direction for specific cells in a figure that I am reading from a matrix.

In the attached figure, I could create the left direction arrow, but I am not getting how to insert a diagonal arrow in the south west direction.

[image]

Apparently, [latex arrow symbol](http://garsia.math.yorku.ca/MPWP/LATEXmath/node9.html) works fine for left arrow, right arrow, up arrow and down arrow, but fails for diagonal arrows.

In the attached image I need to insert arrows in south west direction through cyan cells. How to do this?

Here is the script I am trying,

```
for row=1:size(data,1)
    for col=1:size(data,2);

        if data(row,col)==1   
            rectangle('Position',[col-0.5 row 1 1], 'FaceColor','y','EdgeColor','k', 'LineWidth', 0.1)
            text(col-0.95,row+0.6,'\leftarrow', 'fontsize', 6);

        elseif data(row,col)==2
            rectangle('Position',[col-0.5 row 1 1], 'FaceColor','c','EdgeColor','k', 'LineWidth', 0.1)
            text(col-0.95,row+0.6,'\swarrow', 'fontsize', 6);

        else
            rectangle('Position',[col-0.5 row 1 1], 'FaceColor','w','EdgeColor','k', 'LineWidth', 0.1)            
        end

    end

    set(gca,'Visible','off')  
end
```

**Edit:** 
`Annotation` option will increase the complexities and requires positioning of arrows for every another problem. If one could use latex arrow symbol the problem would become way more easier.

Comment: Did you consider to just draw the vectors, instead of using Latex text for it?

Comment: No, I have no idea. Could you elaborate a little bit more.

Comment: `annotation` may do the job

Comment: @AnderBiguri using `annotaion` would increase the complexities, as the arrow direction would change in other problems where I have noretheast, southeast, southwest, and northwest arrows. Moreover, positioning of arrows will further require lot of effort for every other problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw an arrow in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729784/how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-matlab) See especially [Marsei's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25732096/5211833)

Comment: As a side-note: South-West is the lower left of an image. Are you sure you don't need it South-East (i.e. top left to lower right)?

Comment: @Adriaan I need diagonal arrows to southeast, southwest, northeast, and northwest direction, just like the horizontal arrows in west direction, shown in fig, for the ease of understanding I specifically asked for southwest arrows. Moreover I have 100s f arrows to show, hence, it would be difficult to use `annotation` option.

Comment: Hence, see the duplicate. Also, use your favourite search engine to search for `Stack overflow matlab arrow` and the first ten results are all good SO questions exactly like this problem.

Comment: Can you describe/show why does it fail with diagonals?

Comment: @Mario: I think you should consider looking at the `quiver` function. You won't need the ugly plot. Also, I think you should consider using `pcolor` as well. You can then get rid of your for loops and rectangles and annotations.

Comment: The `'\swarrow'` markup is not supported by MATLAB. The list of supprted characters can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2017a/matlab/ref/text.html#inputarg_Interpreter). You will need a workaround like the ones already suggested.

Comment: @Bernhard I need to show the flow direction using arrow. `pcolor` though efficient doesn't help for arrows, whereas `quiver` function gives different length for arrows based on their values, which should be uniform here.

Comment: @AnderBiguri `\swarrow` is not suppoerted by MATLAB unlike `\leftarrow`, though both are the latex arrow symbols. This is why diagonal arrow failed.

Comment: @Mario `pcolor` can easily replace the grid you are drawing, and in `quiver` you define the length yourself, so I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Bernhard thanks, I will try as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested above, you can use [`quiver`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html) to draw the arrows. Also, [`pcolor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html) is a much better way to plot all the rectangles and color them.

Here is an example for a code that use both of them to create something like what you want:

```
data = randi(3,10)-1; % some random data
% plot the rectangles:
pcolor([data data(:,end);
        data(end,:) 0])
% set the colors to w-y-c:
colormap([1 1 1; 
    1 1 0;
    0 1 1]);
[r, c] = ndgrid(1:size(data,1),1:size(data,2)); % a grid of all the cells
% logical indexing for the arrows:
leftarrow = (data==1);
swarrow = (data==2);
% plot all the arrows in black:
hold on
quiver([r r]+0.1,[c c]+0.5,[-leftarrow.' -swarrow.'],...
    [zeros(size(data)) -swarrow.'],'AutoScaleFactor',0.5,'Color','k')
hold off
set(gca,'Visible','off')
```

And a typical result:
[image: pcolor & quiver]