# quiver() in Matlab 2015b - small arrow heads

Tags: r, matlab

I'm using `quiver()` to show flow magnitude and direction, but the arrow heads are tiny, as you can see in the figures. The arrows are scaled by AutoScaleFactor=0.1, to prevent the lines from overlapping. Changing MaxHeadSize doesn't do anything!

[image: quiver plot[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQTS2.jpg)

I've read ALL the previous questions on changing the arrowhead size and style, and even downloaded some functions from MatlabCentral. But nothing seems to work. I guess the data structure of the quiver plot was changed in one of the recent Matlab versions. Specifically (taken from: [In Matlab how do I change the arrow head style in quiver plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776172/in-matlab-how-do-i-change-the-arrow-head-style-in-quiver-plot)),

```
hq1 = quiver(x,y,u,v);
hkid = get(hq1,'children');
```

results in `hkid=empty`.

When I tried to use `annotation()` I ended up with arrows of odd shape and location.

Any help will be appreciated (including referral to an R package), thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you actually tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18776335/2586922)? (Keep a copy of original file!)

Comment: @LuisMendo: I couldn't find this file path for 2015b. I found refresh.m but it didn't have any of these parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an up-to-date version of the quiver-to-annotation code that control for the arrow size and head width/size separately here:

[In Matlab how do I change the arrow head style in quiver plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776172/in-matlab-how-do-i-change-the-arrow-head-style-in-quiver-plot/18776822#18776822)

Here is the figure

[image]