# Arrow-size in Quiver

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to increase the arrow size in quiver. Apparently, there isn't such a property in matlab. 
I tried changing the following in quiver.m

```
% Arrow head parameters
%alpha = 0.33; % Size of arrow head relative to the length of the vector
%beta = 0.33;  % Width of the base of the arrow head relative to the length
alpha = 100000050.5; beta = 0.5;
autoscale = 0; % Autoscale if ~= 0 then scale by this.
plotarrows = 1; % Plot arrows
```

But it shows no effect. Please use the following example for one of the above curved line.
[image]

**Reproducible example:**

Data:

```
K>> xcor_i, ycor_i

xcor_i =

  -41.9777
  -41.9777
  -41.9777
  -41.9777
  -41.9778
  -41.9780
  -41.9786
  -41.9801
  -41.9833
  -41.9894
  -42.0001
  -42.0180
  -42.0462
  -42.0888
  -42.1509
  -42.2382
  -42.3575
  -42.5163
  -42.7230
  -42.9862
  -43.3151
  -43.7191
  -44.2070
  -44.7877
  -45.4689
  -46.2574
  -47.1585
  -48.1762
  -49.3125
  -50.5676
  -51.9399
  -53.4262
  -55.0215
  -56.7195
  -58.5131
  -60.3942
  -62.3547
  -64.3866
  -66.4821
  -68.6343
  -70.8372
  -73.0858
  -75.3760
  -77.7045
  -80.0689
  -82.4667
  -84.8956
  -87.3524
  -89.8334
  -92.3332
  -94.8451
  -97.3606
  -99.8694
 -102.3593
 -104.8170
 -107.2277
 -109.5757
 -111.8454
 -114.0213
 -116.0888
 -118.0353
 -119.8499
 -121.5249
 -123.0557
 -124.4415
 -125.6852
 -126.7938
 -127.7782
 -128.6532
 -129.4366
 -130.1496
 -130.8154
 -131.4592
 -132.1069
 -132.7845
 -133.5170
 -134.3276
 -135.2369
 -136.2618
 -137.4148
 -138.7034
 -140.1298


ycor_i =

  -14.2165
  -14.2165
  -14.2165
  -14.2165
  -14.2166
  -14.2167
  -14.2172
  -14.2183
  -14.2204
  -14.2245
  -14.2315
  -14.2430
  -14.2606
  -14.2866
  -14.3235
  -14.3742
  -14.4417
  -14.5296
  -14.6411
  -14.7797
  -14.9487
  -15.1511
  -15.3895
  -15.6657
  -15.9813
  -16.3369
  -16.7324
  -17.1672
  -17.6399
  -18.1484
  -18.6901
  -19.2620
  -19.8604
  -20.4815
  -21.1211
  -21.7749
  -22.4386
  -23.1078
  -23.7785
  -24.4469
  -25.1094
  -25.7626
  -26.4037
  -27.0299
  -27.6391
  -28.2298
  -28.8014
  -29.3543
  -29.8905
  -30.4131
  -30.9272
  -31.4388
  -31.9555
  -32.4856
  -33.0377
  -33.6205
  -34.2420
  -34.9091
  -35.6278
  -36.4023
  -37.2352
  -38.1276
  -39.0788
  -40.0868
  -41.1479
  -42.2574
  -43.4099
  -44.5989
  -45.8179
  -47.0600
  -48.3185
  -49.5871
  -50.8597
  -52.1303
  -53.3934
  -54.6435
  -55.8751
  -57.0827
  -58.2606
  -59.4031
  -60.5046
  -61.5596
```

Code:

```
vx=diff(xcor_i);
vy=diff(ycor_i);
goal_vec_x=xcor_i(2:end);
goal_vec_y=ycor_i(2:end);
quiver(goal_vec_x,goal_vec_y,vx,vy,'LineWidth',0.5,'MaxHeadSize',100000,'AutoScale','off');
```

Comment: Please post the rest of the relevant code and consult [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729784/how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-matlab/25730013#25730013). Maybe there is already the solution...

Comment: @thewaywewalk please check now. thx for suggestion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18776822/838992 might help