# Understanding MATLAB's quiver plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to understand the `quiver` function, moreover, what exactly specifies the quiver's origin, direction, and length. I understand it is different from `plotv`.

For instance, the code `quiver(0,1); axis equal` produces:

[image: first example]

which seems to start at `[1,1]`, and end at `[1,2]` for a length of 2. I'm not too sure how MATLAB worked that out?

Secondly, if I provide a vector if inputs such as `quiver([0 0 0 0],[1 2 3 4])`, I obtain:

[image: second example]

So each one seems to start at an integer value, but again I'm not sure how MATLAB is deducing the length or direction?

Lastly, I was trying to plot a sine wave with quivers starting at the origin and ending at the value of the sine wave on the y-axis. This is how far I got:

```
x = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
y = sin(x);
h = quiver(x(1:3:end),y(1:3:end));
```

[image: example 3]

Why do the quivers angle forward? And how can I normalize the arrow heads so they are the same size? I tried accessing the property `MaxHeadSize`, but it only works for the largest one.

Could someone please describe what is going on?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation to `quiver`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html)? It’s quite clear and has lots of examples. Simply type `doc quiver` in MATLAB!

Comment: Hello, yes I did have a read but could still not figure out my simple examples. The `x,y,u,v` inputs were puzzling me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ans 1:** From Matlab's [quiver](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html) documentation, `quiver` accepts either `x, y, u, v` or `u, v`. You seem to be using the later case, ie, providing just the vector's lengths in the x and y direction. In such a case, Matlab does the quiver plot at equally spaced points in the xy plane which happens to start from (1,1). If you do not want this, consider providing `x` and `y` data as well to the quiver function, ie, `quiver( 0, 0, 0, 1 )`.

**Ans 2:** Direction and length of the vectors are being provided by you. Lengths of the vectors in the plot are being **scaled** though [Ref: [quiver properties](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.quiver-properties.html)]. If you do not want this, use `'AutoScale', 'off'` with the quiver function, ie,

```matlab
quiver( [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3, 4], 'AutoScale', 'off' )
```

**Ans 3:** Vectors in the sine graph lean forward because you have provided a non-zero `x` component to the vectors in your quiver command. Try this instead

```matlab
x = linspace( 0, 2*pi, 20 );    % x-coordinates of the vectors' origin.
y = zeros( size( x ) );         % y-coordinates of the vectors' origin.
u = zeros( size( x ) );         % x-components of the vectors.
v = sin( x );                   % y-components of the vectors.

h = quiver( x, y, u, v, 'AutoScale', 'off' );
```

**Ans 4:** Sadly there is no such option to have quiver arrow heads of the same size. All you can do is modify the `'MaxHeadSize'` option to suit your needs. (See the quiver properties reference for more info on this.) Other than this, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18776822) which obtains the desired effect using annotations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I couldn't get my head around the documentation. I will need to play around with your solution in Ans 3 to figure out how it works.

Comment: You are welcome. I have modified the code in ans 3 a little bit. Hope it is clearer now.